# Substitute for skypekit API

Tags: contacts, skype, instant-messaging

I am using skypekit as a service to send messages to clients.
What I need is to add/delete client accounts as contacts, and send instant messages to them.

However, skypekit is going to decommission in about a year.

"Skype URI" is another developement tool. It can send messages, but it is unable to add/delete contacts.

Is there any substitute for skypekit API?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Skype4Py for Python

https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py

Comment: Thanks! But how to ensure that this tool will continue to work after several skype APIs are decommissioned?

Comment: It won't. If Microsoft decides to chop your head off I suggest you migrate to some open platform. I would push my luck with Google Talk APIs.

Comment: Google Talk has now been discontinued as well. No luck there.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen: Darn. Do you have a related link? Other ideas? I'm looking forward for Tox but it is not ready yet http://tox.im/

Answer (score 3):

Please note that Skype4PY is not a solution to this issue. It is build on the Desktop API which is also deprecated.

I am afraid at this time there is no supported way to send messages through Skype pragmatically, except for using the Lync SDKs or APIs. However as these are for enterprise and almost always require you to have a Lync Server installed this may not be appropriate for you either.

Allen Smith
Program Manager
Skype Developer

Answer (score 2):

Since Google Talk has been abandoned as well and there is no substitute for Skypekit yet although support has been extended a bit (Skypekit can't run on the new Windows 8.1 update), I am personally using the Lync API.

[Lync Online](http://products.office.com/en-us/Lync/lync-online-overview-and-features-online-meetings-and-instant-messaging) (as part of Office 365) costs me **$2 a month per user** at this time of writing, and it allows me to chat with Skype contacts too.