# Bad CPU type in executable when doing arch -i386 pip2 install skype4py

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault, skype4py

I have a problem with Skype4Py lib in Mac OS. As I know from documentation in github, in macos skype4py must install with specific arch. But when I try to use `arch -i386 pip2 install skype4py` I get error message `Bad CPU type in executable`. I am not experienced user in macos (this is been a remote control in team viewer) but what I doing wrong? Also I tried use virtualenv and at the start all be ok, but when in shell I make `client.Attach()` I have a segfault. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is not this thing discontinued? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24576166/283676

Comment: No, this is not about my case.  I want to use Skype4Py with runninh Skype. In my Linux Mint everything be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess Skype has finally upgraded their OSX executable to 64-bit architecture and the instructions do not apply anymore.

Please note that Skype4Py and Skype API for desktop are discontinued. Instead, focus your development efforts on Skype web API instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962122%28v=office.16%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link (it's be very usefull in future). I just wanna send some message to some skype ids in my list. May be somebady have idea, how realize it for now? Today I will test Ruby wrapper to skype API (https://github.com/shokai/skype-ruby). Maybe it's working.

Comment: Use Skype web API and JavaScript.

Comment: It is posible to send message without web browser running? I want to send it from script with Skype client.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was not able to solve the problem with Skype4Py on Mac OS. But perhaps someone will be useful to know that I have found a replacement. I used Ruby gem called skype. It works well on Mac OS. So, if you want to send message from script or anything else, just make `gem install skype` and start to write some ruby code :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had Skype4Py working on my Mac running El Capitan (10.11.6) an hour ago and then I started getting this Bad CPU type error after I reinstalled virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper.

After the reinstallation, I guess my system started using the python in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is version 2.7.11. I have another version in `/usr/bin/` that's 2.7.10 and using that fixed it for me. These are the commands that ended up working for me:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python venv
source venv/bin/activate
arch -i386 pip install Skype4Py
arch -i386 python myscript.py
```